# Determine if the given foreign id is owned by the user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

What is good approach to determine if the given foreign id is owned by the user and return collection if found?

I have been doing like this, for example, in the controller:

```
public function showToken(Request $request)
{
  $this->tokenRepo->ownToken($request->user(), $request->toke);
}
```

In the tokenRepo class, the `ownToken` method look like this:

```
public function ownToken($user, $tokenId)
{
  return $user->tokens()->where('id', $tokenId)->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning explicit `true` or `false` value is a good practice. Also if you're checking token for currently logged in user, you could use `auth()->user()`. For example if repo is a model:

```
public function ownToken($tokenId)
{
    return is_null($this->where('id', $tokenId)
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->first());
}
```

Or:

```
public function ownToken($tokenId)
{
    return is_null(auth()->user()->tokens()->where('id', $tokenId)->first());
}
```

Then you'll be able to do this:

```
if ($this->tokenRepo->ownToken($request->token)) { .... }
```

Comment: Why not return collection if found rather than explicit `true` or `false`?  That would reduce second step.

Comment: If you want to use this collection or object then of course you need to return it. But I assumed you want to check if token belongs to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the boolean value of the count being greater than zero, which would reduce the weight of the DB query.

```
public function ownToken($user, $tokenId)
{
  return !! $user->tokens()->where('id', $tokenId)->count() > 0;
}
```

`first()` will translate into `SELECT *`, where `count()` will just do `COUNT(id)`.